# Why does VLC Player play a .ape file all as one song?

Tags: mp3, music, vlc-media-player

I am using VLC Player to play a 350MB .ape file with 12 songs in it.  Is VLC a proper program to play it?  Because it keeps on playing it only as one continuous song instead of 12 separate songs.

Any trustworthy, mainstream software that can play it as 12 separate songs?  thanks.

Comment: Wouldn’t you need a .cue file for the track information?

Comment: Ah, can this .cue file be re-created, say, because between the songs, there usually is silence for 2, 3 seconds.  So a program probably can detect when the gaps are and create the .cue file from it?

Comment: CueMaster only supports MP3, i don't know of any program that can create a cue sheet from APE files (it is created during the ripping and converting process, e.g. with EAC), you will have to convert the files to WAV, chop them to pieces (e.g. with Audacity) and then convert to whatever format you prefer.

Comment: I’m positive these programs exist. But if it’s for just one file, you might want to create the .cue sheet manually instead of installing that program. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cue_sheet_(computing) Should be rather easy and you aren’t forced to rely on that program’s heuristics.

Comment: hm... if it can be everything in one container, then it'd be good... like .mkv, i think it has all video, sound, subtitle files all in 1 file.  Packing the .ape and cue sheet together can be good?  any not good behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like **[Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)**, VLC can play the songs separately by loading the **cue** sheet.

Or use the **[Medieval CUE Splitter](http://www.medieval.it/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=28&Itemid=70)**, a freeware tool that split a single big audio track, mostly an album or a compilation, into the relative individual audio tracks, using informations contained in the associated "CUE" file. Sometimes you can find a big compressed audio file (for example MP3, APE, FLAC, OGG, WAV, WMA, etc...) equipped with a small "CUE" text file that contain informations about tracks title, artist and length.

[image]

*Foobar2000 and Medieval CUE Splitter are freeware.*

Tutorial: **[How to Split APE Files](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Split_APE_Files_22698174)** (with Medieval CUE Splitter)

Comment: VLC does support cue sheets. But of course, you need to have one.

Comment: right, haven't been using VLC since 0.86 or so ... it's been quite a while :)